# how to search for a file in windows using java

Tags: java, file-io, io, fileutils

i want to search for a file in windows just by giving the name of the file,intially i tried to list out all files using this piece of code

```
File[] files = File.listRoots();   
for(File f : files){   
  parseAllFiles(f.getPath());   
}   


...

public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory){   
  File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles();   
  for(File f : filesInDirectory){   
    if(f.isDirectory()){   
      parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());   
    }   
    System.out.println("Current File -> " + f);             
  }     
}
```

but I got an exception saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fileoper.parseAllFiles(fileoper.java:24)
    at fileoper.parseAllFiles(fileoper.java:26)
    at fileoper.parseAllFiles(fileoper.java:26)
    at fileoper.main(fileoper.java:19)
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: You might not have permissions to list the files in root directories. In this case , `File#listFiles` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example. I get a null pointer when trying to open `/root`. When I try to open it via terminal, it just says that I don't have the permissions.

So you basically have a problem with permissions.

The javadoc says :

̀`Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.`

In order to catch this, you should check if `filesInDirectory` is null.

```
public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory){   
  File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles();
  //Added this line.
  if(filesInDirectory != null){   
    for(File f : filesInDirectory){   
      if(f.isDirectory()){   
        parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());   
      }   
      System.out.println("Current File -> " + f);             
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) in Java and then `Files.walkFileTree(startDir, visitor)` to walk the filetree recursively from a starting dir.

`FileVisitor` defines a couple of methods which are called for every File/Directory (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html)). 
Of particular interest is the method

```
FileVisitResult visitFile(T file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
```

which is called for every File. In this method you can check if it is the file you are searching for.

(Use [`SimpleFileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) and override just the `visitFile()` method if you don't need the other methods)

See [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html#filevisitor) for a complete description of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `listFiles()` method directly on file object.*It returns null if file is not a directory*,that's why you are getting *NPE*.So verify first file is dierctory or not and then call the method.
According to [File#listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

> pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned

This is the code to modify

```
public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory)
{        
          File file =  new File(parentDirectory);
          if(file.isDirectory())
         {
           File[] filesInDirectory =listFiles();   
           for(File f : filesInDirectory)
           {    
                    parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());   
            }   

          }else{
               System.out.println("Current File -> " + file);                  
          }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check in `parseAllFiles()` if all files you want to open actually exist by:

```
File fileInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory);
  if(fileInDirectory.exists()){
  File[] filesInDirectory = fileInDirectory.listFiles();
}
```

Then you can realize what file has not been found/created.

The same you can do in the first loop:

```
for(File f : files){  
  if(f.exists()) 
  parseAllFiles(f.getPath());   
}
```